# What happens to a thread that got woken up by pthread_cond_signal() but lost competition for a mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

Regarding this:
[How To Use Condition Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206350/how-to-use-condition-variable)

Say we have number of consumer threads that execute such code (copied from the referenced page):

```
while (TRUE) {
    s = pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while (avail == 0) {   /* Wait for something to consume */
       s = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
    }
    while (avail > 0) {   /* Consume all available units */ 
        avail--;
    }
    s = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

I assume that scenario here is: main thread calls pthread_cond_signal() to tell consumer threads to do some work.

As I understand it - subsequent threads call pthread_mutex_lock() and then pthread_cond_wait() (which atomically unlocks the mutex). By now none of the consumer threads is claiming the mutex, they all wait on pthread_cond_wait().

When the main thread calls pthread_cond_signal(), following the [manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html), at least one thread is waken up. When any of them returns from pthread_cond_wait() it automatically claims the mutex.

So my question is: what happens now regarding the provided example code? *Namely, what does the thread that lost the contest for the mutex do now?*

(AFAICT the thread that won the mutex, should run the rest of the code and release the mutex. The one that lost should be stuck waiting on the mutex - somewhere in the 1st *nested* `while` loop - while the winner holds it and after it's been released start blocking on pthread_cond_wait() beacuse the `while (avail == 0)` will be satisfied by then. Am I correct?)

Comment: +1 so you can upvote some answers. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `pthread_cond_signal()` is generally intended to wake up only one waiting thread (that's all that it guarantees). But it could wake more 'accidentally'. The `while (avail > 0)` loop performs two functions:

- it allows the one thread guaranteed to be woken up to consume all queued work units
- it prevents additional 'accidentally' awakened threads from assuming that there's work to be done, when there might not be since the initial thread would have handled all of them.

It also prevents a race condition where a work unit might have been placed on the queue after the `while (avail > 0)` has completed, but before the worker thread has waited on the condition again - but that race is also handled by the `if` test just before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Basically when a thread is awakened, all it knows is that there *might* be work units for it to consume, but there might not (another thread might have consumed them).

So the sequence of events that occurs when `pthread_cond_signal()` is called is:

- the system will wake one or more threads waiting on the condition
- all the threads that are awakened will then try to acquire the mutex - only one of them can acquire it at any particular moment, since that's the purpose of a mutex
- that thread will then proceed, perform the work in the `while (avail > 0)` loop, then will release the mutex
- at that point one of the other threads that were previously woken up will acquire the mutex and work the same loop, then release the mutex. Generally, there will be no work units available anymore (since the first thread would have consumed all of them), but if another thread  had added an additional unit (or more), then this thread would handle that work
- the next thread will acquire the mutex and perform that same set of logic

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. Maybe I haven't expressed it clearly but I wanted to know what, after the wake up call, is the thread that lost contest for the mutex **doing now**? I assume it has to stop running the code because the mutex has been claimed by another thread (winner) and we're in the critical section, BUT the question is:** *if the loosing thread returned from `pthread_cond_wait()` where is it "stuck" now?* ** Does it somehow, automagically return to the `pthread_cond_wait()` (@Nikolai) ? @Hasturkun almost answered my question.

Comment: ...continued: I'm guessing, because `pthread_cond_wait()` on exit atomically aquires the mutex (winner case), the loosing thread will stop immediately (before checking again for `while(avail==0)` condition) after it returned from its `pthread_cond_wait()`. Am I correct?

Comment: The 'losing' thread will be blocked on the mutex before returning from `pthread_cond_wait()` since `pthread_cond_wait()` must acquire the mutex for the thread before letting it return.  Once the 'winning' thread releases the mutex, the losing thread will be able to acquire it and proceed to return from `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: Note that this is not what many modern implementations do. Punch "wait morphing" into your favorite search engines to see a more modern, and better performing, approach.

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_cond_wait()` has to acquire given mutex once signaled/woken up. If another thread wins that race, the function blocks until the mutex is released. So from the application point of view it doesn't return until current thread holds the mutex. The wait is always done in a loop (`while (avail == 0) { ...` above) to make sure that *application* condition we are waiting for still holds (buffer not empty, more work available, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The thread that lost the contest wakes up once the mutex is unlocked, checks the condition again, then goes to sleep on the condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

> When any of them returns from pthread_cond_wait() it automatically claims the mutex.

Ah, but it doesn't. Not "automatically", that is, depending on what "automatically" means. You might be confused by the "atomic" semantics of `pthread_cond_wait`; but that semantics is played out on the entry side: a thread is somehow registered for waiting on the condition before giving up the mutex, so that there isn't any window during which the thread no longer has the mutex, and is not yet waiting on the variable.

Each thread which returns from `pthread_cond_wait` has to acquire the mutex and therefore contend for it. Those which lose the race for the mutex have to block on the mutex, similarly as if they called `pthread_mutex_lock`.

The way the mutex is acquired on exit from `pthread_cond_wait` can be modeled as a regular `pthread_mutex_lock` operation. Essentially, the threads have to queue up on the mutex in order to exit. Each thread which acquires the mutex then returns from the function; the others have to wait until that thread gives up the mutex before they are allowed to return.

No thread woken up by the signal gets the mutex "automatically", in the sense of somehow being transferred ownership due to special eligibility. Firstly, on a multiprocessor, a woken thread can lose the race to a thread already running on another processor which snatches the mutex, if it is available, or else queue to wait on the mutex ahead of the thread which received the signal. Secondly, the thread which calls `pthread_cond_signal` may itself not have given up the mutex, and may continue to hold it indefinitely, which means that all the woken threads will queue up on a mutex lock operation and none will emerge from `pthread_mutex_lock` until that thread gives up the mutex.

All that is "automatic" is that the `pthread_cond_wait` operation doesn't return until acquiring the mutex again, and so the application doesn't have to take the step to acquire the mutex.