# pthread and synchronization

Tags: c++, pthreads, signals, mutex, deadlock

I have a question about muti threading synchronization..
We suppose that we have 2 pthread and an fifo queue.
Thread 1 will insert the elements in this queue and thread 2 will extract these elements from the same queue.
I implemented the two operations of my queue: push and pop.

```
void push(element e) {

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
myVector.push_back(e);
pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

Element pop() {

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if(myVector.size() == 0) 
pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex);
//extract the element from the queue;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
```

the thread2 will then have this life cycle:

```
while(myBoolFlag) {
    Element theElement = myQueue->pop();
usleep(500000);

}
```

this code can lead to deadlock situations?
before of wait, must I unlock the mutex?

Comment: It's fine, but you need to use `while` not `if` to check the predicate (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6206350/768469)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No deadlocks visible.

`pthread_cond_wait()` implicitly releases the mutex.

However, you could move `pthread_mutex_unlock()` to be called before `pthread_cond_signal()`.

Comment: To be clearer, it releases it for the duration of the wait, and reacquires it prior to returning.

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for adding this, in fact, essential part of `pthread_cond_wait()`'s behaviour.

Comment: No, you should NOT move the unlock before the signal, because it buys you nothing and can cost performance (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6312416/768469)